# Whitelisting for Google Apps for Business domain for internal usage

Tags: google-schemas

*Sorry for asking it here but it is only place to ask (https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/support)*

As Google Apps for Business customer we would like to use Gmail-Schema (mainly the "ViewAction" type) for our internal emails:
* server status emails
* order emails

We are already added the DKIM entry to our DNS and it's working with same-user-test.

Question:
Should we still apply via *Gmail Schema Whitelist Request* form? 
Or is there some other approach to get our domain whitelisted

Comment: This looks like a good question for Server Fault, but Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fill the whitelist request form with your details and describe your use case, specifying that you are interested in internal emails.